# Using factor smooths as varying coefficients: Identifiability and identifiability constraints

Tags: mgcv, identifiability

I would like to use mgcv to build a model in which the effect of a covariable is modelled using a factor smooth as varying coefficient, i.e. the model

```
model1 <- gam(y ~ 1 + t + id + s(t, id, bs = "fs", xt = "ps", m = c(2, 1), by = x), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
```

where the effect of x is time-varying (variable t) and this time variation is group-specific (variable id).

However, for interpretability I would like to include the fixed main effect of x as well, i.e.

```
model2 <- gam(y ~ 1 + t + id + x + s(t, id, bs = "fs", xt = "ps", m = c(2, 1), by = x), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
```

In addition, I decided to split the varying coefficient into main and interaction effects, i.e.

```
model3 <- gam(y ~ 1 + t + id + x + s(t, bs = "ps", m = c(2, 1), by = x) + s(id, bs = "re", m = c(2, 1), by = x) + ti(t, id, bs = "fs", xt = "ps", m = c(2, 1), by = x), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
```

Although my models seem to work, I did not find any justification in the mgcv documentation.
Therefore, I have the following questions:

1. Is it problematic/instable in model1 to include the linear effect of t and the random intercept for id in my model, too, when I also use these variables to build my varying coefficient for x?
2. Is it problematic/instable in model2 to include the linear effect of x as well?
3. If model1 and model2 are not problematic/instable, is there still any problem with model3?
4. If there are any instabilities/problems the cases 1) - 3), is there a possibility to overcome these?

Thank you very much!